# Getting Nth sub-directory's files from an input path

Tags: c#, filesystems, system.io.directory

How can i Get Files from nth sub-directory of an input Directory using C#.

Comment: You need to do several things before this will be answered 1. Show what you've tried so far, and 2. Be more specific about what exactly you are expecting to have returned given a particular input. It's unclear what `the HM-34 directory from each directory` means.

Comment: @tnw leave all the things .. just think i have a driectory D:\aashto material\TS_1A   and this directory have further many folders and i want to reach to some nth folder how can i do that ?

Comment: You pretty much just repeated what you already have in your post. Please re-read my comment and add the necessary details to get your question answered.

Comment: Perhaps think about it this way: If you had a list of all directory names (not just the immediate subdirectories of `D:\aashto material`, but of all their sub-directories, too), which would be the ones that you'd pick, and what would be the exact criteria? Does it suffice that the directory path contains an element named `HM-34`, or does it have to be at a particular depth in the hierarchy? Your problem can then be reduced to 3 subproblems: 1. How do you get a flattened list of the whole directory hiearchy? 2. How do you filter it? 3. What filter do you apply? Tell us more about #3, please!

Comment: @stakx i don't need the exact directory name like HM-34 i just want to get the some 4th or 5th or u can say some nth directory name in each of these directories . because all these directories contain further directories

Comment: @user3261313: Sorry but that still doesn't explain what you need. When  you say the "n-th directory name", do you mean the n-th entry in a list of directory paths; or do you mean extracting the n-th part of a directory path for each directory path? Example: Let's say you have built a list of directories: `D:\A`, `D:\A\Aa`, `D:\A\Ab`; `D:\A\Ac`, `D:\B`, `D:\B\Ba`, `D:\B\Bb` etc. According to your understanding, is the 2nd directory name simply `D:\A\Aa` (because it's the 2nd in that list), or is it `Aa`, `Ab`, `Ac`, `Ba`, `Bb`, etc. (because these are at the 2nd level of the hierarchy)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution i have done . and its working .

```
foreach(var dir in Input_Folders)
        {
            string f = dir;

            for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
            {

                string path = sub_dir(f);
                f = path;
            }
}
```

n is the nth child and the method sub_dir(string) is

```
public string sub_dir(string path)
        {

            string[] direct = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
            string s = direct[0];
            return s;
        }
```

this will go to the nth child of the each input directory .. check this out .